# JAXB Error: unexpected element when unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

Could someone help me understand why I'm getting this error:

*javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"items"). Expected elements are <{}item>*

I've new to JAX-B but been stuck on this all day, I really don't understand whats happening and any help is really appreciated, thanks a lot.

Item Class:

@XmlRootElement

```
public class Item {

private String itemID;
private String itemDescription;

//need to have a constructor with no params
public Item(){

}

//Constructor: sets object vars
public Item(String itemID, String itemDescription) {

    this.itemID = itemID;
    this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
}

@XmlAttribute
//getters and setters
public String getID() {
    return itemID;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    itemID= id;
}

@XmlElement
public String getDescription() {
    return itemDescription;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    itemDescription = description;
}
```

Unmarshalling code:

```
resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/testProject/rest/items");
    ClientResponse response= resource.get(ClientResponse.class);
    String entity = response.getEntity(String.class);

    System.out.println(entity);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Item item = (Item) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(entity));


And this is the XML i'm trying to parse:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <items>
      <item id="1">
        <description>Chinos</description>
      </item>
      <item id="2">
        <description>Trousers</description>
      </item>
</items>
```

Here is the Web Service that is creating the XML:

```
@GET
            @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
            public List<Item> getItemsBrowser(){

                java.sql.Connection connection;
                java.sql.Statement statement;

                List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();


                ResultSet resultSet = null;

                try {
                    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                    statement = connection.createStatement();

                    String query = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS";

                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

                    // Fetch each row from the result set
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                      String a = resultSet.getString("itemID");

                      String b = resultSet.getString("itemDescription");

                      //Assuming you have a user object
                      Item item = new Item(a, b);

                      items.add(item);
                    }


                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return items;
            }
```

Comment: Tell us more about your environment. Are you moving your code new server? What type of webservice it is (java code first (or) WSDL first)?

Comment: I've updated with my Java RESTful webservice code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you're creating the JAXBContext from is Item.class, but the XML contains a list called items which in turn contains distinct item entries. You would need another class that wraps a

```
List<Item>
```

for this to work.

Here's a full working example:

The Items class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Items {

    private List<Item> items;

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

Note that there is an @XmlElement annotation on the items property, because the actual elements are called "item" in the XML.

The Item class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Item {

    private String itemID;
    private String itemDescription;

    // need to have a constructor with no params
    public Item() {}

    public Item(String itemID, String itemDescription) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
        return itemID;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        itemID = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getDescription() {
        return itemDescription;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        itemDescription = description;
    }
}
```

And a unit test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.junit.Test;

public class JAXBTest {

    @Test
    public void xmlIsUnmarshalled() throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Items items = (Items) um.unmarshal(new File("items.xml"));

        assertNotNull(items);
        assertNotNull(items.getItems());
        assertEquals(2, items.getItems().size());

        assertEquals("Chinos", items.getItems().get(0).getDescription());
        assertEquals("Trousers", items.getItems().get(1).getDescription());

        assertEquals("1", items.getItems().get(0).getId());
        assertEquals("2", items.getItems().get(1).getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but could you exaplain a little more? I need to edit this line? - JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);

Comment: Thanks that is great, only thing is the Id is null when tested. The description is being obtained but not the Id, any idea why the Id is null for each item? I'm using "Items items = (Items) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(entity))"; instead of your xml file example

Comment: Scratch that it was a problem with capital letters, thanks for your answer

Comment: I stumbled across that as well, forgot to tell you - in my code example, you can see that I renamed getID() to getId() :-)

Comment: FYI - Since @flexer7661 is using the Jersey client APIs, here is a way you can still leverage the JAXB binding, but avoid the need for the `Items` class:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10215514/383861

Answer (score 0):

Since youa are using the Jersey cleint APIs you could do the following and avoid creating the `Items` class:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource resource = client.resource(""http://localhost:8080/testProject/rest/items"");
        List<Item> items = resource.accept("application/xml").get(new GenericType<List<Item>>(){});
        System.out.println(items.size());
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html